# elementary os on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, desktop-environment, elementary-os

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop I tried to install Pantheon desktop enviroment because I tried it on the elementary os before and I liked it but the last version of elementary os is depended on a Ubuntu 12.04 and I wanted to use Ubuntu 14.04. I searched how to install it and I installed with these commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:elementary-os/daily 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pantheon
```

when those commands didn't work I typed this:

```
sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop
```

but it didn't work correctly this is a list of the problems:

- I can't change languages with <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd> although I enabled changing language with them in settings
- time isn't displayed
- the top right information: wifi,the icon of turning of the computer etc.. (it's in the picture in the top left because I am using a language making it at the top left)
- some of the shortcuts that I enabled don't work like : <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>backspace</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but you could wait until the next version of Elementary OS (codenamed `Freya`) is released.  It's currently available as a Beta.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know a solution for shortcuts, but for the indicators: search for files beginning with "indicator" in /etc/xdg/autostart, edit with admin rights and add "Pantheon;" so that the line looks like "OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;Pantheon;"

For missing time, the information on https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1356698 could help: probably this is a problem with language information.

Anyway: new installation of (current) stable freya is recommended.